# SharePoint Online - Choice field not saving selection

Tags: sharepoint-online, choice-field, multi-select

I have a document library in which there is a choice column set to all multiple selections.  I have been recently made aware that when new items are added to the library, a selection can be made but that selection is saved once the upload is complete.  Attempting to edit the library in Quick Edit mode will allow for one or more selections to be made, but they are not retained once you stop editing the library.

This is not a required column and there are no workflows.  This is just a basic document library.  Any suggestions of why it might not be saving the selection made?

Thanks

Comment: Is it retaining just one value or more than one value too?

Comment: It's supposed to allow for multiple values, but it's not retaining any values.

Comment: So found a post referencing an issue with custom xml causing the issue with being unable to update a multi-select choice column.  I inspected the documents of the files I could not update and removed the offending xml (which was not placed their intentially) and it worked.  Anyone heard of this or if a better fix is forthcoming?  Having to edit all offending files this way could get unmanageable.

Comment: Here is the link to the reference post.  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/e0c00ffd-3d14-419e-aaeb-06cf9081348b/choice-column-not-updating?forum=sharepointgeneral

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that there was custom xml in the actual documents in the library which was causing the issue.  Found no resolution, ended up going a different route with the library and its contents.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new document library using the default template, and add choice column (Checkboxes) to the library, then check if it works.

In my test, it works.

[image]

And then check if you have some custom code in the page.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it has worked for me to change the column to single selection. Save a value in the column and then change it to multiple selection. After that, it already correctly saves me several values.