# Radio button in edit form - modern list experience

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

I have created a modern custom list and I have radio button on the form, but when I attempt to edit the item more than once, the choice column does not change - has anyone else experienced this and anyone know a workaround ?

Comment: Is it similar to [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/252598/sharepoint-online-choice-field-not-saving-selection)??

Comment: kinda , but I only have 2 radio button, it is either off or on.. if you edit the form once after setting the value to say 'yes', and you want to turn it 'off'. it may work once but after that it doesn't. I cannot see why but damn its annoying

Comment: Is there any custom script or anything added in page?

Comment: no... it just doesn't change... if I change the list to classic view it works fine - but that's not want I need.

Comment: Is there any error or something in browser's console window?

Comment: no it saves fine, but the column does not change

Comment: thanks, I have noticed there is a validation script on the list, which is incorrect that is making the column go strange.

Comment: Then please close the question by adding that as an answer, so people do not spend time trying to answer this question (that is already resolved)

Answer (score 0):

Validation code in the list that cause the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check if there any custom script or code is added in page?

Also check the column or list validation added or not.

If you found anything. Correct it so that it will save your choices are desired.